# Which event gets fired when an element is shown to the user?

Tags: jquery, jquery-events, deferred-rendering

I have a page with lots of images. It doesn't make sense to have the browser load them all, if the user hasn't scrolled down yet to where the images are.
I thought of binding the `img` element to an event handler that fires when the containing `div` would be visible (in the sense that the user has scrolled enough such that the element is in the viewport). This handler will then rewrite the `src` attribute and the image will load.

What's the event I am looking for?

Comment: You could just use any lazy load jquery plugin such as this one: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Comment: There's no event as such. The technique you are looking for is called lazy loading. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8509878/jquery-lazy-loading-image-with-throttling

Answer (score 1):

There is no native jQuery event doing what you want. You'd need to use the `scroll` event to get the scroll position, get visible images, and load them.

There already is plug-ins doing this for you. Maybe the appear jQuery plug-in is what you're looking for: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-appear/

This may be a duplicate of this question: [Make images load when they enter visible section of browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736215/make-images-load-when-they-enter-visible-section-of-browser)

Comment: Technically his question asks 'what event gets fired'. While I agree with you that it is much better to use a mature plugin, it isn't the answer to his question

Comment: That's why I just edited the question ;) Thanks for the comment though.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

 // if user has scrolled to 250px 
 if ($(this).scrollTop() > 250){ 
    // load your images,
 } 
})
```

A better approach would be placing a `div` at bottom and using `mouseenter` event to detect if user wants more picture.

```
$('#the_bottom_div').mouseenter(function(){
   // If user has placed mouse on bottom,load images (like facebook does)
})
```